# Invoke-SqlCmd is broken, is there a better wrapper for SMO/SqlCmd.exe?

Tags: sql-server, powershell

The bugs in the Powershell Invoke-SqlCmd are legion and the SqlServer tools team seems to continue to keep their bug-list private and ignore the problem.  It stops writing after the first empty resultset.  It double-executes after an error.  These bugs still exist in the current version of the SqlServer powershell module.  So, I need to stop using it.

That said, I have a lot of code that leverages Invoke-SqlCmd.  In particular, it uses the SQLCMD-specific features like :r and GO and token-replacements through $(variablename).  So I'm loath to rewrite using ADO.Net objects that would lose these features.

Is there any better powershell wrapper-module for SMO/SqlCmd.exe?

Comment: Double execution problem was fixed in Cumulative Update 2 for SQL Server 2016 SP1

Comment: I installed the latest SqlServer module just today and am still seeing it.

Comment: Hmmm, just tested it, not seeing it. Link to fix: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4010159/fix-invoke-sqlcmd-cmdlet-executes-a-query-statement-multiple-times-if

Comment: installing the latest SqlServer module is not the same as installing the CU2 for SQL Server 2016 SP1

Comment: Okay, that solves one part - the double-execute/dropping error messages is fixed.  But the other part - the insane "empty result blocks all results" bug is still live.  Either way, I've been burned enough by this tool that I'm hunting for an alternative.

invoke-sqlcmd "select 'foo' where 0=1;select 'bar'"